# C++ How to declare out of constructor (Error C2065 undeclared identifier)

Tags: c++, class, constructor, copy

I am a newbie in programming, and in my homework, the task is to swap the second elements in different copied maps, where if I change something in the copied version, the original map changes as well, but I don't know how to write the copy function.

```
template <class T, class P>
class map_swapper
{
public:
    map_swapper(map <T, P>& Cmap)
    {
        map<T, P> & copym(Cmap);
    }

    void swap(const T &t1, const T &t2) // I don't know if this function here is good or not because of the undeclared identifier error I can't get here, it is just a guess.
    {
        P a;
        a = copym[t1];
        copym[t1] = copym[t2];
        copym[t2] = a;
    }
};

int main()
{

    std::map<int, std::string> mapS1;
    map_swapper<int, std::string> mapS2(mapS1);

    mapS1[0] = "zero";
    mapS1[1] = "one";
    mapS1[2] = "two";

    std::map<int, int> mapI1;
    map_swapper<int, int> mapI2(mapI1);

    mapI1[0] = 0;
    mapI1[1] = 1;
    mapI1[2] = 2;

    mapS2.swap(0, 2);
    mapI2.swap(0, 1);

    for (typename std::map <int, std::string> ::iterator it = mapS1.begin(); it != mapS1.end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << it->first << " ";
        std::cout << it->second << std::endl;
    }
    for (typename std::map <int, int> ::iterator it = mapI1.begin(); it != mapI1.end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << it->first << " ";
        std::cout << it->second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get `Error C2065 'copym': undeclared identifier` since I declared  'copym' in the constructor, but don't know how to pull the declaration out of there and use the constructor only for assignation.

The output should be this:

```
0 two
1 one
2 zero
0 1
1 0
2 2
```

Comment: We're you told that you had to write a class `map_swapper`? Because that's a complicated and strange way of doing things. It's must more straghtforward to just write a function to do the swap, and not write a class at all.

Comment: To answer you specific question, move `copym` out of the constructor and put it in the class as a private member. Because it's a reference you must use an initialiser list to bind it, you can't assign to a reference (assignment to a reference always assigns to what the reference is bound to, not to the reference itself).

Comment: Yes they told us to use a class for it to make it a bit complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my version of your code. Untested, should at least compile though.

```
template <class T, class P>
class map_swapper
{
public:
    map_swapper(map <T, P>& Cmap) : copym(Cmap)
    {
    }

    void swap(const T &t1, const T &t2)
    {
        P a = copym[t1];
        copym[t1] = copym[t2];
        copym[t2] = a;
    }
private:
    map<T, P> & copym;
};
```

Still think using a class to do this is a bit weird.